# Angularjs add element to DOM when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, addition

I want to create a table which contains dynamic Content. When clicking on an element, the Details should Show up in the next line. So i creatied the following:

```
<table ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="word in ['A', 'B', 'C']">
        <td><!-- Some Information, Image etc --></td>
        <td ng-click="showDetails(word)">{{word}}</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- This is only visible if necessary -->
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="currentDetail == word">
        <td colspan="2" ng-attr-id="{{'Details' + word}}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I have the following js code:

```
angular.module('maApp', []).controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, $document, $compile){
    $scope.showDetails = function(word){
        var target = $document.find("Details" + word);

        //I checked it - target is NOT null here

        //target.html("<div>Test</div>");
        //target.append("<div>Test</div>");
        var el = $compile("<div>Test</div>")($scope);
        target.append(el);

        //Show tr
        $scope.currentDetail = word;
    };
});
```

I also tried the commented Solutions above but nothing of it works (The tr is showing up however). I guess there is something wrong with `$document.find("Details" + word)` but I don't know what.

Ultimately I want to add an `<iframe>` and the source would contain the `word`.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for weird non-angulary DOM manipulation: All you need is this.

HTML:

```
<table ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="word in ['A', 'B', 'C']">
        <td><!-- Some Information, Image etc --></td>
        <td ng-click="showDetails(word)">{{word}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="currentDetail==word" ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan="2">Details {{word}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, $document, $compile){
    $scope.showDetails = function(word) {
        $scope.currentDetail = word;
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20074/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I know I can do that but I have one Problem with it... (That's why I wrote that I want to add `iframes`). When I do it like this I have thousends of iframes on my Website and it becomes unresponsive...

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should probably use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. With `ng-if` the associated elements don't exist in DOM until the expression evaluates to `true`, compared to `ng-show` where it just uses CSS show/hide. So only one iframe should exist at a time with `ng-if`. The code is pretty much the same as with the previous example. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20075/

Answer (score 1):

$document.find in jqlite is limited to tag name only. You have to add jquery for anything more.
See what is suported in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to accomplish it without jQuery. is there an angularjs way to do it?

Comment: BTW: I also tried: `target = angular.element(document.getElementById(...))` which also didn't work

Comment: You could maybe use `ngSanitize` with  `ngBind` or `ngBindTemplate`  or `ngBindHtml` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: That sounds pretty good! Can I use variables e.g. `{{word}}` inside that html?

Comment: Yes. you can build the html as a sting so you can essentially do this `$scope.htmltobind = "<div>"+word+"</div>";` in your controller

Answer (score 1):

you have all you need built into angular already,  you don't need the Javascript at all.

see [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYq1dt?p=preview)

```
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 30px;"></td>
        <td>
          Name
        </td>
        <td>Gender</td>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="person in people">
        <td>
          <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
          <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly I have the same Problem as in @Fissio's answer: I want to add iframes and with thousands of iframes (at the end) the site becomes unresponsive...

Comment: this is the difference, i used `ng-if`  and not `ng-show`, which prevents your content to show in the DOM at all... so you will only have an `iframe` if the item is expanded

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that. Excellent answer then :-) Thanks